# Using CNAME to display the content of a subfolder on a different domain

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, cname-record

I have clients that have their own stores hosted in subfolders.

E.g. http://example.com/store1

I would like to have http://example.com/client1 display on their own domain e.g. http://www.store1.com

Can this be achieved using CNAME Records? I do not want this process to be manual and have to setup virtual hosts for each store.

UserVoice is doing this with subdomains: https://feedback.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/18423-set-up-your-own-url-domain-for-uservoice I'm looking for something similar but for subfolders.

Comment: It sounds like you just need name based virtual hosts. Start by reading this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html and then you should be able to ask more targeted questions.

Comment: You can't do this with DNS, it's at the host level not the web server level - it's a different layer in the OSI stack. Using Nginx you'd use proxy_pass within a location.

Comment: You have to set up virtual hosts for each store. Even Uservoice is doing that.